# Hackmd image don't show in Github

Tags: github, hackmd

https://github.com/neilyes52/SoCLab/blob/parity_generator/parity_generator/parity_generator.md

I want to show an image in Github. I use the syntax `![](https://hackmd.io/_uploads/BJkuM-QA2.png)`.
Nothing shows in Github.
I can see the image link in the source code. What should I do to fix this issue?

I expect the image shows in the preview. But nothing shows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P857f.png)

Comment: I get a 403 on the two images when I try to load them, which may be your problem. Try with a image that is publicly downloadable.

Answer (score 0):

please write just `<img src="your image file path here" alt="image" />` this code in your github readme code and your problem will be solved. **remember you added image on your repo file.**